# To revert an appointment status through API

Tags: api, hl7-fhir

I am trying to find out a resource in fhir. The scenario is, I'm marking a patient who has arrived to the clinic against a particular encounter, later realized that the patient, whom I have marked as arrive is an incorrect patient. Now I wanted to cancel the arrived event (the event should not be visible in the front end application) against the encounter. Kindly suggest which API resource will suit this purpose?

Answer (score 1):

If the server's business rules allow, you should be able to update the Appointment to change the status back to 'booked'.  There aren't really any 'event' representations in FHIR.  A system that had subscribed to the Appointment would receive a notification when the status changed from 'booked' to 'arrived' and would receive another notification when it was changed back to 'booked'.

Comment: We want the history of the "arrived" status to be removed from the resources life cycle. How to achieve that.

Comment: You can't generally remove history.  You can capture in Provenance that the reason for the change was correction, but the reality is that for a period of time, the status did show 'arrived' and it's possible that action could have been taken (and costs incurred) on that mistaken basis.